# How to write unit test for a WebFilter that is writing a Reactor Context? Specifically, what and how do I mock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, spring-webflux, reactor

Suppose I have this simple webfilter that just writes a reactor context

```
WebFilter filter = (serverWebExchange, webFilterChain) ->
    webFilterChain
        .filter(serverWebExchange)
        .contextWrite(Context.of("my-key", true));
```

I'd imagine the test will look something like this:

```
StepVerifier.create(filter.filter(serverWebExchange, webFilterChain)
    .expectAccessibleContext()
    .hasKey("my-key")
    .then()
    .verifyComplete();
```

But I'm not sure how to mock the `webFilterChain` to make sure the Context is written.

```
Mockito.when(webFilterChain.filter(any()).thenReturn(???)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_testing_the_context

Comment: The reference shows how to test the context and I believe I have already set that up properly. The question I have is more about how to mock the webfilter

Comment: Why not just check what the filter returns?

Comment: I need to mock the `webFilterChain` and tell it what to return for `.filter()`. What is that thing, which then calls `.contextWrite()`?

Comment: you can either check the javadoc of `WebFilterChain` or inspect the method inside an IDE. It will tell you what the return type of `filter(exchange)` is. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/WebFilterChain.html

Comment: and if it return a `Mono<Void>` you can just return a `Mono.empty()`

Comment: @kane have you found any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem and this is my solution

```
WebFilterChain filterChain = filterExchange -> Mono.empty();
MockServerWebExchange exchange = MockServerWebExchange.from(
    MockServerHttpRequest
        .get("/your-url")
        .header("my-key", "value"));

StepVerifier.create(yourFilter.filter(exchange, filterChain))
    .expectAccessibleContext()
    .hasKey("my-key")
    .then()
    .verifyComplete();
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/cors/reactive/CorsWebFilterTests.java

Answer (score -1):

Because the method `webFilterChain.filter(any())` does not return anything (it is a void method), I would suggest to verify if the method was called:

```
Mockito.verify(webFilterChain, times(1)).filter(any());
```

Comment: the return type of the `filter()` method is `Mono<Void>` which is not the same as `void`. Not mocking will most likely result in a null pointer exception